# Set Calendar to next Thursday

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm developing an app in Android which have a service that must be executed every Thursday and Sunday at 22:00

What I do need, is to set a Calendar to that day and time. However, I'm not sure about how to do it.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

This is giving me a calendar with the current date and time.

I know I can **add** days, minutes, hours, etc. But, is there any way to directly `setNext("thursday")`?

I don't want to do many maths there. I mean I'm looking for an answer which doesn't need to calculate how many minutes/hours/days are left till next thursday.

Thank you!!

Comment: The calendar api is horrendous for doing what you want. It is awful.

Comment: and how would you do that, @Zavior?

Comment: With a lot of pain and time. Certainly not without a lot of maths.

Comment: @Zavior I've found an answer. Not many maths and not much time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the below solution simpler, a bit more portable as it doesn't involve much math. Once you set it to Thursday I believe you can use the`setTime()` method on the calendar object to set it to 22:00.

```
//dayOfWeekToSet is a constant from the Calendar class
//c is the calendar instance
public static void SetToNextDayOfWeek(int dayOfWeekToSet, Calendar c){
    int currentDayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            //add 1 day to the current day until we get to the day we want
    while(currentDayOfWeek != dayOfWeekToSet){
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        currentDayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    }
}

  //usage:
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  System.out.println(c.getTime());
  SetToNextDayOfWeek(Calendar.THURSDAY,c);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Wow. Totally true, so easy to understand and with 0 maths.

Answer (score 1):

Not many maths, solved this, so clean:

```
    int weekday = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  
    if (weekday!=Calendar.THURSDAY){//if we're not in thursday
        //we calculate how many days till thursday
        //days = The limit of the week (its saturday) minus the actual day of the week, plus how many days till desired day (5: sunday, mon, tue, wed, thur). Modulus of it.
        int days = (Calendar.SATURDAY - weekday + 5) % 7; 
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
    }
    //now we just set hour to 22.00 and done.
```

Credit to: http://www.coderanch.com/t/385117/java/java/date-Monday

I just adapted and explained the code.

Comment: I arrived at almost the same result, albeit with a messier solution using Calenders set-method. Yours is much clearer solution :P

Comment: Nice solution. I used to friday.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
c.add(c.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);
```

or

```
c.add(c.DAY_OF_YEAR, +7);
```

Comment: This is adding 7 days to the actual day. Not what I want, as if I run this on a Monaday, it will be executed again next monday.

Answer (score -1):

calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.THURSDAY);