# Setting Calendar fields in Android

Tags: java, android, calendar, dayofweek, java.util.calendar

setting the day field in a calendar using

```
    myCalender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
```

does is put set the day to the next Friday or the past Friday or maybe the closest?

Also what if I don't set the year or any other field for the calendar, what are the default values?

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Yet. It’s complicated. But don’t use `Calendar`, see below.

From [the documentation of the two-arg `set` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-):

> Sets the given calendar field to the given value. The value is not
>   interpreted by this method…

So during this call it just sets the day-of-week field to Friday. The year, month and day-of-month stay the same, that is, the date isn’t effectively changed. Yet.

If and when the `Calendar` eventually computes and resolves its fields,

> If there is any conflict in calendar field values, `Calendar` gives
>   priorities to calendar fields that have been set more recently. The
>   following are the default combinations of the calendar fields. The
>   most recent combination, as determined by the most recently set single
>   field, will be used.

If you have only set the day of week (which will likely have introduced a conflict with the other fields), the following combination applies:

> `YEAR + MONTH + WEEK_OF_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK`

So it will pick the Friday in the same week.

What defines a week is determined by the `Calendar`’s first-day-of-week field. Its initial value is determined by the `Calendar`’s locale, and you can control it through `getFirstDayOfWeek()` and `setFirstDayOfWeek()`. This in turn means that the default behaviour for a `Calendar` in a European locale previously set to a Sunday will go back to the previous Friday, whereas a `Calendar` in the US locale would pick the next Friday instead.

If you have also set other fields after setting the day-of-week but before fields are calculated, it is a different story.

### Default values?

Generally the default values of `Calendar` fields are current date and time in your JVM’s time zone (usually, but not always, the same as your device’s time zone).

### You don’t need to care

The good news is that you don’t need to care. The `Calendar` class is long outmoded anyway, and it was also (seen in retrospect) poorly designed, so you should not use it. Instead use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. Depending on your need, you may for example use `LocalDate` for a date or `ZonedDateTime` for a date and time of day with time zone.

The modern classes offer you a great deal of better clarity and more flexibility. For example:

```
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Saipan"));

    // the following calls do what the method names say
    ld = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
    ld = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
    ld = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
    ld = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));

    // set to Friday in the same ISO week
    ld = ld.with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.getValue());

    // set to Friday in the same US week
    ld = ld.with(WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.dayOfWeek(), 
            DayOfWeek.FRIDAY.get(WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.dayOfWeek()));
```

### Question: Can I use `java.time` on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On (older) Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Answer (score 0):

Its will be nex Friday

Friday, 23 February 2018 year., 20:44:17.353

Default values is this Year

Answer (score 0):

> what are the default values

```
 Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance(); //the default is the current time/date
```

> next Friday or the past Friday or maybe the closest?

next time/date, therefore, the answer is next Friday.

see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that using     `myCalender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY)`
***is a complete mess***, it may set the day to next or the past Friday, I have been trying a lot but couldn't figure the logic!

Anyway, all I needed was to set the calendar to a particular day in the next week, and I managed to do this using the *answer to that question* ..

[set the calendar to next Thursday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051622/set-calendar-to-next-thursday)