# Periodic Work Request running immediately - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to create a notification to be triggered on a schedule. I want the notification to show once a day around a set time (doesn't have to be exact). So what I'm trying to do is create a PeriodicWorkRequest that runs every 24 hours, and delay the start of the work request to the time of day I want it to run. I can get it running on a schedule, but whenever I create it, it just runs right away. I found some questions saying you can use .setInitialDelay() on the builder, however this doesn't seem to be available in the Xamarin Work Manager API. I have also tried .SetPeriodStartTime() on the Builder class after finding the method in the builder class definition, but this doesn't seem to be affecting anything.

```
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StartNotificationRemindersMessage>(this, "StartNotificationRemindersMessage", message => {
                TimeSpan startDelay = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2) - DateTime.Now;

                PeriodicWorkRequest notificationsWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder.From<NotificationsWorker>(1, TimeUnit.Days).SetPeriodStartTime(startDelay).Build();
                WorkManager.Instance.Enqueue(notificationsWorkRequest);
            });
```

Here I'm creating the periodic work request and trying to add a 2 minute delay to the start.

And here is the NotificationsWorker class.

```
    class NotificationsWorker : Worker
    {
        public NotificationsWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParameters) : base(context, workerParameters)
        {

        }
        public override Result DoWork()
        {
            CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("GCS Reminder", "Testing reminder notifications");
            return Result.InvokeSuccess();
        }
    }
```

If someone can show me what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use  `AlarmManager` and `Calendar ` to execute your task.  `Calendar ` could shedule a time, `AlarmManager` could executed when arrival the time. You can see my this thread :https://stackoverflow.com/a/61356731/10627299

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT This works exactly as I need as long as the app is open. How can I get it to continue running after closing the app?

Comment: If you closed your application, I cannot found a effective way to achieve it, But If application run in the background, you can use foreground service to keep the AlarmManager running continuously.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension method named SetPeriodStartTime.  It's extremely hard to find any documentation on it, but I've been experimenting with it and it appears to do the trick.

E.g.

```
   PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder
     .From<YourWorkerClass>(repeatInterval, flexInterval)
     .SetPeriodStartTime(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))
     .Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

setInitialDelay() is now available on the builder in the Xamarin Work Manager API for Xamarin Android

I use setInitialDelay() to make sure PeriodicWorkRequest is delayed for a while you get a WorkRequest so Just cast it to a PeriodicWorkRequest

```
PeriodicWorkRequest notificationsWorkRequest = (PeriodicWorkRequest)PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder.From<YourWorkerClass>(repeatInterval,repeatIntervalTimeUnit).SetInitialDelay(repeatInterval,repeatIntervalTimeUnit).Build();

WorkManager.GetInstance(Android.App.Application.Context).Enqueue(notificationsWorkRequest );
```

Then to use it in Xamarin.Forms I use a dependency service, messaging center, or I just define it in the Android Main activity class depending on my reason for using work manager

example would be

```
PeriodicWorkRequest notificationsWorkRequest = (PeriodicWorkRequest) PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder.From<NotificationsWorker>(24, Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeUnit.Hours).SetInitialDelay(24, Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeUnit.Hours).Build();
```